# How to make a circle follow the mouse pointer?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to make 2D shooter with Python `tkinter`.
Here are my progress:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

c = Canvas(root, height=500, width=500, bg='blue')
c.pack()

circle1x = 250
circle1y = 250
circle2x = 250
circle2y = 250

circle1 = c.create_oval(circle1x, circle1y, circle1x + 10, circle1y + 10, outline='white')
circle2 = c.create_rectangle(circle2x, circle2y,circle2x + 10, circle2y + 10)

pos1 = c.coords(circle1)
pos2 = c.coords(circle2)

c.move(circle1, 250 - pos1[0], 250 - pos1[2])
c.move(circle2, 250 - pos1[0], 250 - pos1[2])

beginWall = c.create_rectangle(0, 200, 500, 210, outline='white')

def move_circle(event):
   pass

c.bind('<Motion>', move_circle)

root.mainloop()
```

But I am trying to make the function called `move_circle` make `circle1` and `circle2` follow the mouse pointer . Something like this `c.goto(circle1, x, y)`.

Comment: Hi, Harry, welcome to Stack Overflow. I can't answer your question, but I can suggest you to use a better title for it. "I am trying to make a game" is not a question, and doesn't give the relevant information of what is your problem. How about renaming it to something like "How can I make a circle follow the mouse in tkinter?"?

Comment: Ok thx I will try it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by modifying the coordinates of the two "circles" in the `move_circle()` event handler function. A simple calculation is done to make it so the centers of these two objects are positioned at the "tip" of the mouse pointer (see image below).

Note, I also modified your code to more closely follow the [PEP 8 - Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) coding guidelines.

```
import tkinter as tk

# Constants
CIRCLE1_X = 250
CIRCLE1_Y = 250
CIRCLE2_X = 250
CIRCLE2_Y = 250
SIZE = 10  # Height and width of the two "circle" Canvas objects.
EXTENT = SIZE // 2  # Their height and width as measured from center.

root = tk.Tk()

c = tk.Canvas(root, height=500, width=500, bg='blue')
c.pack()

circle1 = c.create_oval(CIRCLE1_X, CIRCLE1_Y,
                        CIRCLE1_X + SIZE, CIRCLE1_Y + SIZE,
                        outline='white')
circle2 = c.create_rectangle(CIRCLE2_X, CIRCLE2_Y,
                             CIRCLE2_X + SIZE, CIRCLE2_Y + SIZE)

pos1 = c.coords(circle1)
pos2 = c.coords(circle2)

c.move(circle1, 250-pos1[0], 250-pos1[2])
c.move(circle2, 250-pos1[0], 250-pos1[2])

begin_wall = c.create_rectangle(0, 200, 500, 210, outline='white')

def move_circles(event):
    # Move two "circle" widgets so they're centered at event.x, event.y.
    x0, y0 = event.x - EXTENT, event.y - EXTENT
    x1, y1 = event.x + EXTENT, event.y + EXTENT
    c.coords(circle1, x0, y0, x1, y1)
    c.coords(circle2, x0, y0, x1, y1)

c.bind('<Motion>', move_circles)

root.mainloop()
```

Here's a screenshot of it running on my Windows computer:

[image: screenshot of GUI app running]

Comment: when you halved it why did you type two //

Comment: what does the root.mainloop() do?

Comment: Harry: `//` is the [floor division](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#binary-arithmetic-operations) operator and is used so the result is an integer instead of floating-point value. `mainloop()` is a universal widget method that contains a loop that continually processes keyboard and mouse events from the user. All `tkinter` apps must call it at some point to give the GUI itself a chance to "run". Here's some [documentation](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/universal.html) I found about it.

Comment: Careful, `//` does *not* guarantee "an integer instead of floating-point value".  Conside `range(SIZE // 2)`  It works if `SIZE` is `10` but throws an error if `SIZE` is `10.0` -- you may still need an `int()` wrapper depending on what you're doing.  Perhaps it guarantees an *integral* value but not an *integer* one?

Comment: @cdlane: While what you say is true, floor division of integers results in an integer rather than the floating-point value regular division would have produced—exactly what's intended in this usage case. In fact everything would still work in this case if `SIZE` had been set to `10.5` so I guess it's not that important of a point.